# Filter configuration on a different window C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, filter

I have a program that gets some products from a database based on some filters (stock quant., name contains X, price etc.) to setup the filters i open a new Window with all the parameters and when they click save it creates a file that the main window opens to read the filters.
Is there a more efficient way of doing this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I believe there is a more efficient way for what you want to do. You can create a window that after you close it, gives back some value. (like an OpenFileDialog)

First off, if you haven't already, create a class the describes a set of filters.

```cs
class FilterSet
{
    public string NameSubString { get; set; }
    public int MinStock { get; set; }
    public double MinPrice { get; set; }
    public double MaxPrice { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

After that add this `FilterSet` class as a public (private set) property to your window that you use to input the filters.

```cs
public partial class SearchFiltersWindow : Window
{
    public FilterSet Filters { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

Use this to set all the input parameters from the window.

Now make sure you have an **Ok** and a **Cancel** button on that window. This will be used to indicate that the user made a successful input or not. Set the IsDefault and IsCancel to `true` respectfully on the two buttons and set them up to both close the window. Also make sure to set the **DialogResult** property to `true` when pressing the OK button.

```cs
private void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)       
{
    this.DialogResult = true;
}
```

Now the only one thing remaining is to get the `FilterSet` from the window after it's closed. Here is the code that you can use in the `MainWindow` to open the filter window and get the inputted parameters from there when it's closed.

```cs
SearchFiltersWindow window = new SearchFiltersWindow();
if (window.ShowDialog() == true) // ShowDialog() will return the subwindow's DialogResult when it's closed
    DoStuffWith(window.Filters);
```

Comment: Seems the thing that im looking for, i will try it out. Thanks ^^